# SQL select from table where key in array group by column

Tags: sql, postgresql

given a table bills

```
# bills
id  | name    | amount  | user_id
1   | jumper  | 100     | 1
2   | gopper  | 200     | 1
3   | jumper  | 150     | 2
4   | blobber | 300     | 3
```

and a table users

```
# users
id  | name
1   | John Doe
2   | Mike Marley
3   | Bill Mickane
```

when I perform the query

```
select * from bills where user_id in (1,2) order by name, amount desc
```

I get

```
# bills
id  | name    | amount  | user_id
2   | gopper  | 200     | 1
3   | jumper  | 150     | 2
1   | jumper  | 100     | 1
```

but what I want is (and all other columns)

```
# bills
name    | amount
gopper  | 200   
jumper  | 250
```

how would this be achived?

I'm tempted to use

```
select * from bills where user_id in (1,2) group by name order by name, amount desc
```

but can't as the `group by` would also need to list the other column names and end up not merging the two rows as desired.

p.s. I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 5):

If you just want those 2 fields you can use the Aggregate SUM():

```
 SELECT 
          name, 
          SUM(amount) 
     FROM 
          bills 
     WHERE 
          user_id IN (1,2) 
     GROUP BY 
          name 
     ORDER BY 
          name, 
          amount
```

However, assume you wanted more then just those two fields...
nested queries should help you out.

```
SELECT
 m.id, m.name, t.userId, t.amount 
FROM Bills m
 INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT
          user_id as userID,
          SUM(amount) as amount
   FROM
          bills
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t
ON t.UserID = m.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `PGError: ERROR:  column t.userID does not exist`, when I change the initial select to `select * from bills m...` the results are not grouped by name, even changing the inner join to group by name instead of user_id does not work as desired (all bills where `user_id in (1,2)` grouped by name). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    name, SUM(amount) 
FROM 
    bills 
WHERE 
    user_id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY 
    name 
ORDER BY 
    name, amount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM bills where user_id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name, amount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, sum(amount) as amount
from bills where user_id in (1,2) 
group by name 
order by name, amount desc
```